# Ruby on Rails: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column:

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

```
SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups"
INNER JOIN "groups_interests" ON "groups"."id" = "groups_interests"."group_id"
WHERE "groups_interests"."interest_id" = 1

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: groups_interests.interest_id: SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" INNER JOIN "groups_interests" ON "groups"."id" = "groups_interests"."group_id" WHERE "groups_interests"."interest_id" = 1

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: groups_interests.interest_id: SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" INNER JOIN "groups_interests" ON "groups"."id" = "groups_interests"."group_id" WHERE "groups_interests"."interest_id" = 1
```

I think I have a misunderstanding about foreign keys and the has_many relation

To get the error I used rails c

```
Interest.find(1).groups
```

I also want this command to run correcty

```
Groups.find(5).interests

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :project_id
  has_many :students
  has_many :group_interests
  has_many :interests, :through => :group_interests
  belongs_to :project

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end


class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :group_interests
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_interests

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

end

class GroupInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :group_id, :interest_id

  belongs_to :groups
  belongs_to :interests

end
```

I got the idea to do this from [ruby on rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many):

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :project_id
  has_many :students
  has_and_belongs_to_many :interests
  belongs_to :project
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end


class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end

class GroupInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :group_id, :interest_id    
end
```

You need to change your table structure on `join_table`. See the link provided for that.

Answer (score 2):

**The reason for your error:** there are two typos

```
class GroupInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :group_id, :interest_id

  belongs_to :groups      #should be :group
  belongs_to :interests   #should be :interest

end
```

- `Group` has_many `:group_interests` (plural)
- `GroupInterest` belongs_to `:group`  (singular)

**EDIT** - Do not use `has_and_belongs_to_many` unless you are sure that you will never need a new attribute in the association table. `has_many :through` is much more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

```
class GroupInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :group_id, :interest_id

  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :interest

end

Group.find(5).interests
```